# How to explain disagreement on one point, or method in simple sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions

I have fitted several models in statistics. Then I use goodness-of-fit to evaluate the performance of each model. The results show that each test selected a different model. I want to explain this using academic and simple English sentences.

I tried this:

> The goodness-of-fit does not agree on one of the fitted models.

I feel it is a very poor sentence. So, how to improve it.

Comment: It is a little hard for me to understand a couple of things.  Firstly, what do you mean by "Each model selected a different model"  Secondly, why do you think this is a poor sentence.  I think you are "anthropomorphizing" goodness-of-fit.  Perhaps correcting that will help.  But finally, since I don't really know what your problem is, I don't think I can write an answer.  Please specify the problem, rather than just asking for improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the sentence "The results show that each model selected a different model." I think what you are saying is, "The goodness-of-fit does not show that any model is better than the others". If this is so then state it in words something like:

The goodness-of-fit does not show any of the fitted models to be superior to (or you may use the words "better than") the others.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue that I can find with your original sentence is "goodness-of-fit".

Unless this is a statistical "term of art"(in which case, it's use in a statistics or statistics-adjacent academic paper is fine) it should be replaced. Likewise, "fitted models" (with a basic background in statistics, I am familiar with the concept of finding an approximate curve or model for data points, and fitting the most appropriate model or equation to them, e.g. through Newtonian regression, but I am unaware of this being referred to as a "fitted model". Is this your term, or an accepted term in the higher reaches of the field?), and "agree" (I'm more familiar with terms like "matches", "correlates," "conflicts", etc. being used, but again not incredibly familiar with higher level statistics).

As a native speaker the following sentences sound fine to me:

> The "goodness-of-fit" evaluation does not pass one of the models.

> The "goodness-of-fit" heuristic does not match one of the models.

> The output of the "goodness-of-fit" function conflicts with one of the models.

> The "goodness of fit" analysis and the selected model do not agree over the range between X and Y.